# How to access pandas groupby values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I want to access values of a groupby. I want to compare between them.

Here is how I created my groupby dataframe:

```
SideStepped_by_ObstDist_by_Sex = daten_csv.groupby(['ObstacleInterspace', 'Sex', 'Sidestepped']).agg({'Sidestepped': 'count'})
SSbObS = SideStepped_by_ObstDist_by_Sex.groupby(level=[0, 1]).apply(lambda g: g / g.sum())
```

Here is what I get:

[image: output]

I would like to compare between two percentage values of the last 'Sidestepped' column. How can I access them? I want to compare between two of the three in the screenshot marked perecentages (the 1st and 3rd one). How to do that? How to access these specific values?

**EDIT:**

Here is my data:

[image: dataframe]

Comment: can you please post some data, so that we can replicate what you have

Comment: You can use `diff` to do so, after the `groupby`. 
Post the DF data so we can help you with testing prior to posting the code.

Comment: you can use `.first()`, `.last()`, `.get_group()` on a groupby object

Comment: I added a data sample, so you can see in which form it is. ObstacleInterspace is a categorical variable with 4 possible values: 0.0, 0.5, 0.75 or 1.7. Sex is a categorical variable with 2 possible values: 'm' or 'f'. Sidestepped is the target class, with 2 possible values: 1 or 0.

Comment: Is it clear, or do you need more information?